# Separate a string of characters space-separated of dataframe in different columns

Tags: r

I am pretty new at using R and I have some data that I need to tidy a bit before I can use it. Basically I have a dataframe with a bunch of rows and columns and in every cell of this dataframe I have a string of 20 numbers of 1 and zeroes ("0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0").

Now I am trying to separate every number of a field having each number in a new column (1 field would be 20 columns). After that I would like to convert these newly separated strings into numbers. I will show a small sample of the data. Here I would need the numbers separated in 40 columns and 3 rows:

```
df<-data.frame(
"V1" = c("0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ","0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ","1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "),
"V2" = c("0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ","0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ","0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 "))
```

As you can see a good way to separate each number of a string would be treating the space as a delimiter, but I am not having any luck with that. I tried my luck with `df<-lapply(strsplit(df, " "), as.numeric)` but the dataframe can't be treated with this function. I tried then `df<-lapply(strsplit(as.character(df), " "), as.numeric)` 
That way it separates correctly but making the full dataframe as a character messes up the data.

I suppose that it's easier than I think but I still lack skill in this code.

Comment: Trry with `read.fwf` or `read.table(text = as.character(df$V1), header = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` to convert multiple columns into separate columns.

```
splitstackshape::cSplit(df, names(df), " ")

#   V1_01 V1_02 V1_03 V1_04 V1_05 V1_06 V1_07 V1_08 V1_09 V1_10 V1_11
#1:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#2:     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#3:     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

#   V1_12 V1_13 V1_14 V1_15 V1_16 V1_17 V1_18 V1_19 V1_20 V2_01 V2_02
#1:     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#2:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#3:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

#   V2_03 V2_04 V2_05 V2_06 V2_07 V2_08 V2_09 V2_10 V2_11 V2_12 V2_13
#1:     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
#2:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#3:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0

#   V2_14 V2_15 V2_16 V2_17 V2_18 V2_19 V2_20
#1:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#2:     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
#3:     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Note that I have used `names(df)` here since you want to convert all the columns into separate columns. If you have additional columns and want to separate only few of them, you can also do

```
splitstackshape::cSplit(df, c("V1", "V2"), " ")
```

Comment: I tried your code and it seems that works like a charm, but now has a class of "data.table data.frame" even if I check the class of a single cell. If I want to use this as an integer it would be fine to leave this way or I should change its class. I tried making an ``df<-`lapply(df,as.numeric)``` and later putting it together again as a dataframe with ```df<-as.dataframe(df). This now gives me a dataframe with numeric cells, this would be correct or there is a better way?

Comment: @Marc It is okay to keep as `data.table` as well but if you want to have it as data.frame, `df<-as.dataframe(df)` should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Easier option is `read.table` (no packages used)

```
read.table(text = as.character(df$V1), header = FALSE)
```

For multiple columns, use `lapply`

```
lapply(df, function(x) read.table(text = as.character(x), header = FALSE))
```

Comment: I tried this and it changes the dataframe "df" to 2 lists instead of a full dataframe with all the data ordered. Trying to put this together in a simple way I have written ```df<-as.data.frame(df)``` and I think it is fine. This way I should give me a dataframe with every number shown as integer in each cell, right? Thank you very much in advance, it worked pretty well!

Comment: @Marc  It would be `do.call(cbind, lapply(df, function(x) read.table(text = as.character(x), header = FALSE)))`

Answer (score 0):

I found both answers equally good but the use of `cSplit` made the posterior process better I think. What I finally did to obtain the result:

```
df<-cSplit(df, names(df), " ")
df<-lapply(df,as.numeric)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
```

I suppose that this can be done with less lines of code but this way is more understandable for me. Thank you very much for your answers!